# LINQ to List: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to calculate the sum of a column where my condition match. The records that have in the list(lstSumQty) for column "Quantity" is in string format (Note: As this data is coming from excel file which is upload by the end user. So, Quantity column sometimes in a string or in decimal).

Due to column string DataType, the system throws an exception: Specified cast is not valid, How to cast it or resolve?

**Data in list**

```
 Unit  Quantity
 "t"    "10"
 "t"    "05"
 "kg"   "14"
 "t"    "02"
```

The result should be:
 **tUnitTotal** = 17

**See the below piece of code**

```
 tUnitTotal = lstSumQty
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Where(row => row.Field<string>("Unit") == "t")
   .Sum(row => row.Field<decimal>("Quantity"))
   .ToString();
```

Instead of List, I'm also ok with DataSet or DataTable using LINQ.

Any help would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generic type-argument (`<decimal>` in your case) does not indicate what you **want** it to return, but what it **is** in the database.

So you need to convert your strings to numbers before calculating their sum:

```
tUnitTotal = lstSumQty.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("Unit") == "t")
    .Sum(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row.Field<string>("Quantity")))
    .ToString();
```